# Algolia error import dependency - Tutorial

Tags: android, synchronization, algolia, instantsearch

I can't import algolia instantsearch for android:

```
compile 'com.algolia:instantsearch-android:1.+'
// This will automatically update to the latest v1 release when you build.
```

**I have the  error Gradle project sync failed.**

This is the tutorial: https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-android/getting-started.html

Comment: Failed with what error?

Comment: failure to implement compile 'com.algolia:instantsearch-android:1.+'

Comment: You need to use `implementation`.

Comment: it's the same unfortunately

Comment: The version should also be 1.13.0 not 1.+

Comment: thanks!!!,  I had "offline work" in the gradle configuration